# Python class interdependencies

Tags: python, class, inheritance, class-structure

I have a python class that serves as a baseclass for further subclasses. It contains a methods that should act on all subclass the same, e.g. I want to put it in the base class. The problem is, that this method should return a new instance of the subclass. But I since the baseclass is located before the definition of the subclass, I can not create a new instance of the subclass, as it is not known in the scope of the baseclass:

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def convert_child_classes(self, newclass):
    newvalue = MakeUsableInNewclass(self.value)
    newattr = MakeUsableInNewclass(self.subclassattr)
    return newclass(newattr, newvalue)


class Child1(Base):
  def __init__(self, subclassattr, value)
    super(Child, self).__init__(value)
    self.subclassattr = subclassattr

  def MethodForSubClassAttr(self):
    ...do sth with self.subclassattr...


class Child2(Base):
  def __init__(self, subclassattr, value)
    super(Child, self).__init__(value)
    self.subclassattr = subclassattr

  def SomeOtherSubClassAttrMethod(self):
    ...do sth that is related to this class attr...
```

I if I have an instance of Child1 I want to be able to do some stuff with its data and then return an instance of the Child2 with the new values when calling convert_child_classes(Child2):

```
A = Child1('someattr', 5)
B = A.convert_child_classes(Child2)
```

now B should be an instance of Child2 with a value that was calculated form Child1. But since Base class does now know what Child1 or Child2 is, it can not initiate the new class.

Comment: Which stuff are your talking exactly on doing, @Torilla?
Because if you're using attributes from `Child1`, then you can just operate them from the `Base Class` without an issue.
Regarding to instantiate `Class2`, you can receive the `Child2` as an argument, as you already do, but when you `return newclass(newvalue)`, you should add both argumentss from your `Child2 __init__` function, what it'd not shown here

Comment: the idea is that there are many childclasses of baseclass, but they are interrelated and can be converted into each other. For a practical example just think a Baseclass that represents length, and a child class that represents meter and one that represents yards and one inches. I want to be able, if I have an instance that represent 5 meters, that I can convert it to a Inch class for example.

Comment: perfect! So you should use one metric as reference to your `BaseClass`. Now, for each `Child` instance, create a variable such as `self.conversion` that will store the conversion value between both metrics. 
Now, when you call `convert_child_classes`, make the calculation before assigning to the `new class`, using this `self.conversion` that all classes will have implemented, so you don't need to care which Class it's coming from. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: But if I call Child2(newattr, newvalue) i get an ValueError as the BaseClass des not know what Child2 .

Comment: I would be inclined to do this by: (1) defining some canonical base unit (2) each class knows how to convert itself to base unit (3) each class has a factory classmethod which accepts other class, calls its `convert_to_base_unit` method, then creates an instance of itself from that value.

Comment: I got your problem, @Torilla, and just added the answer here below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682559/10642035
Just let me know if it solves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem:
 
1. Actually you're using `Child` in the `super` and it's wrong, as it should be the name of the class you're operating on, in this case `Child1` or `Child2`. 
2. I'd add Base as an abstract class, to ensure it won't be instantiated (as I got from your question it's the case). 
3. since the method `MakeUsableInNewClass` is mandatory to be implemented, I'd add as an `abstractmethod` to ensure implementation on the Child ones.

So the correct code would be:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Base(ABC):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def convert_child_classes(self, newclass):
        newvalue, newattr = self.MakeUsableInNewclass()
        return newclass(newattr, newvalue)

    @abstractmethod
    def MakeUsableInNewclass(): pass

class Child1(Base):
    def __init__(self, subclassattr, value):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(value)
        self.subclassattr = subclassattr

    def MakeUsableInNewclass(self):
        newvalue = self.value #do operations
        newattr = self.subclassattr #do operations
        return newvalue, newattr

class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self, subclassattr, value):
        super(Child2, self).__init__(value)
        self.subclassattr = subclassattr

    def MakeUsableInNewclass(self):
        newvalue = self.value #do operations
        newattr = self.subclassattr #do operations
        return newvalue, newattr
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work (untested):

```
class Measurement:

    @classmethod
    def from_other(cls, other):
        base = other.convert_to_base_unit()
        converted = cls.base_to_unit(base)
        return cls(converted)

    @classmethod
    def base_to_unit(cls, value):
        # Let the subclass implement this
        raise NotImplementedError

    def convert_to_base_unit(self):
        # Let the subclass implement this
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Implemented this way, the base class doesn't need to know anything about the subclasses.  The base class provides the template method (`from_other`) and the subclasses provide the implementation.